# MarkLogic Query Console using GET to save file

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am currently investigating a weird problem which I have using the `MarkLogic Query Console`. When I edit a file and click the save button the browser shows the message

> Query Console lost connection to the server.
> Attempting to re-establish connection.

In the server logs I found this error:

> Socket peer name error: getpeername <ip-addr>:8000: Transport endpoint is not connected

But this only happens when the file I want to save *exceeds a certain size* (about 3.5 kB).
I suspect that something in the (networking) infrastructure I use might be causing this issue, so I started to look at the request which is sent by my browser.

I was very surprised to see that it uses a `GET` request to send the contents of the file, I would have expected a `POST`. Actually, when the file gets bigger, the URL (and thus the sent content) is truncated at some point, which is probably causing my issue.

My question is: why is it using a `GET` request? Is is possible to change it to a `POST` somehow? I think this would solve my problem.

BTW, I am using MarkLogic 9.0-7.2 currently, not sure if this is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The save action should be done via POST, for security reasons and to avoid max-length of URL.

This issue has since been addressed, and will perform a POST in newer versions of MarkLogic.

I just verified that when saving a document via Query Console edit in 10.0-5.2 the document content is sent via POST and successfully saved an 8MB file.

You should upgrade to the latest version of MarkLogic.

Comment: An upgrade to 9.0-13.2 already solved the problem, now the console uses `POST`